# Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes

Hi guys I encrypted school project but my AES saved txt has been deleted, I pictured it before and I filled a new file. But new AES key file is not equal to the typed in jpeg file. Which character is wrong I couldn't find it. Could you please help me.

Pic : https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAXzl.jpg

Text file : http://textuploader.com/dfop6

Comment: That's really not how these things work...  You should [read this](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Answer (score 0):

If you directly convert bytes with any value to Unicode you may lose information because some bytes will not correspond to a Unicode character, a whitespace character or other information that cannot be easily distinguished in printed out form.

Of course there may be ways to brute force your way out of this, but this could easily result in very complex code and possibly near infinite running time. Better start over, and if you want to use screen shots or similar printed text: base 64 or hex encode your results; those can be easily converted back.